# How to invoke a generic method from JScript.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, generics, types, jscript.net

There is an old .ASPX page using "javascript" (JScript) as the page language.

And there is a C# method in a referenced assembly that should be invoked.

```
public void X Locate<X>() where X: IX
```

Using C# this method can be invoked by supplying the type parameter explicitly.

```
var o = locator.Locate<XImpl>();
```

- In JScript, how can a generic method be called with an explicit type parameter?

---

I've been looking around the [dated/introductory JScript documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85xxsf4(v=vs.100).aspx) and have been unable to find suitable information dealing with invoking such generic methods.